# Java using scanner to access array elements

Tags: java, arrays

I've created an array 8 elements long using the scanner class. I'm trying to accept user inputs via scanner and print out the value at that index location. eg if the user enters '2', it prints out the value at the second element. I've searched on google but all the resources are how to use the scanner to input data into an array, not using the scanner to retreive data back. the only way I thought of is by using a ridiculous amount of if else statements but there must be a cleaner way to do it in a loop?

This is my array, I've used the scanner to fill my array. Now, on prompt, the user must input a number from 1 to 8. If they input 1, print out solution[0]. Input 8, print out solution[7] etc. Hope its easier to understand now

```
    String[] solution = new String[8];
    Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in );
    for( int i = 0; i < solution.length; i++ ){
        System.out.println( "Enter solution:" );
        solution[ i ] = scan.next();
    }
    scan.close();
    Scanner scan1 = new Scanner( System.in );
    String selection;

    System.out.println("Enter an int between 0 and 7 to retrieve the Selection: ");
    selection = scan1.next();
    int i = Integer.parseInt(selection);

    System.out.println( "The Selection is: " + solution[i] );
```

Comment: added some code, although I doubt its very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is difficult without any code, but basically, use the scanner to get the input into string `selection`, get the integer value into `int i` with `int i = Integer.parseInt(selection);`, then `myArray[i]`.

Comment: Whats the reason I have to store as a string and parse it to an int, rather than just take it as an int in the first place?

Comment: Because I forgot about `Scanner.nextInt()` :) `Integer.parseInt()` is how I would typically get an `int` value out of command line arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You have to read an int, and use this when getting the value stored at the specified index.

A way to do this is the following:

```
yourArray[scanner.nextInt()];
```

Where `scanner` is the `Scanner` object.

To catch the excpetions you may receive when reading things you assume are numbers, you could do this:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
try {
    yourArray[scanner.nextInt()];

} catch(IllegalStateException | NoSuchElementException e) { // <--- Java 1.7 syntax, in case you wonder
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: how come I have to store the value as a string. Are the index numbers of an array not classed as int?

Comment: I was thinking of two different solutions at the same time. I've updated the answer to better explain what should be done.

Comment: I received errors with yourarray[scanner.nextInt()];   posted updated code above

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

then output:

```
urArray[input.nextInt()];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class array1
 {
 public static void main(String args[])
 {
 int arr[]=new arr[100];
 int i;
 Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.pritln("Enter the Number of Element less than 100");
 int a=sc.nextInt();
 System.out.println("Enter the Number");
 for(i=0;i<a;i++)
 {
 arr[i]=sc.nextInt();
 }
 System.out.println("List of Elements in array");
for(i=0;i<a;i++)
{
System.out.println(arr[i]);
}
}
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer. SO exists not just to answer questions but to teach people the how and why of coding.